# ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable?

Tags: python, django, docker

И так, я получаю ошибку

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'JSONField' from 'django.db.models' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/__init__.py)
```

зашел в терминал в докере и прописал `python3.8 -m pip install -U -I django` чтобы удалить предыдущую версию django и установить новую, последнюю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в логе этого **/ims_api_1**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 12, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

чтобы пофиксить эту ошибку, мне нужно в терминале прописать `docker stop [CONTAINERS]`, затем `docker rm [CONTAINERS]`, после, когда я пишу `docker-compose up` и захожу в логи этого api, снова вижу

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'JSONField' from 'django.db.models' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/__init__.py)
```

такой вот круговорот получается и я не знаю как решить эту проблему

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
  PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN pip install -U pip setuptools wheel \
    django==2.2.6 \
    django-cors-headers==3.1.1 \
    django-currentuser==0.4.2 \
    django-debug-toolbar==2.0 \
    django-filter==2.2.0 \
    django-gtin-fields==0.1.2 \
    django-mptt==0.10.0 \
    djangorestframework==3.10.3 \
    djoser==2.0.3 \
    pillow==6.2.1 \
    psycopg2-binary==2.8.4 \
    sentry-sdk==0.13.1 \
    sphinx==2.2.1 \
    uwsgi==2.0.18

WORKDIR /opt/cron-ims/api/
COPY . .

RUN cd docs && make html

RUN chmod +x "./entrypoint.sh"
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 80
ENV PORT 80

CMD ["uwsgi", "./ims/uwsgi.ini"]
```

Не знаю какие еще файлы вам показать, но я всегда на связи и покажу любой файл который потребуется

Спасибо всем!

Comment: `cannot import name 'JSONField'` — ну тут очевидно, что вы установили слишком старую версию Django

Comment: @andreymal,  у меня не получается посмотреть версию django, но на скрине ведь видно, что установилась 3.2.5 - это разве старая версия? В Dockerfile я не знаю как изменить версию django, мб нужно прописать новую версию или как?

Comment: У вас в докерфайле написано `django==2.2.6`. Если не знаете как работать с докерфайлом — ну значит почитайте какую-нибудь документацию про докер сначала

Comment: @andreymal, насколько я знаю, нужно заменить версию django в `dockerfile`, я заменил с 2.2.6 на 3.2.5, остановил все контейнеры, удалил их, прописал `docker-compose up` и снова получил `ImportError: cannot import name 'JSONField' from 'django.db.models'`

Comment: Команда `docker-compose up` не занимается пересборкой образов, для этого нужно добавить опцию `--build`. Почитайте что-нибудь про докер всё-таки